# How to split the import data using importxml or importhtml

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would appreciate some help with the following two scenarious which I presume you would use the split function, the two queries I have:
(1) How to split headers and data in each cell, imported data is displayed as follows:
I use  `=importxml(A1,F1)`

A1 is the url:

```
https://www.tradingview.com/markets/stocks-australia/sectorandindustry-sector/communications/
```

and F1 is the Xpath:

```
//*[@id="js-category-content"]/header/div/div[3]/div/div
```

Imported data is displayed with data and header displayed together in the same cell as follows:

```
Col1        Col2            Col3            Col4             Col5
23Stocks    67.368BMkt Cap  19.335MVolume   −1.26%Change    −2.54%Perf Month
Col6             Col7
−3.98%Perf Year −4.61%Perf YTD
```

What I would like is to have it split into two rows, headers in first row, and related data in row 2. eg as follows:

```
 Col1    Col2      Col3      Col4      Col5        Col 6       Col7

Stocks  Mkt Cap   Volume    Change  Perf Month  Perf Year   Perf YTD
23      67.368B    19.335M  -1.26%    -2.54%      -3.98%      -4.61%
```

---

(2) The second issue I have is how to extract text data when the imported data is seperated by two pipes.

I use =importhtml(A1,"table",11), A1 is: htps://www.finviz,com, the out put is: Consumer Cyclical | Auto Manufacturers | USA. The output I need is the text between the two pipes. How do I extract "Auto Manufacturers"?

Comment: Please make your question readable. Also. Use 1 question for each part.

Comment: Thanks marikamitsos for the reply this can now be closed. I will add my second query in a new request.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

You should get deeper inside the HTML structure in order to get only the row you need. now you are selecting an external `div` so the content will be squashed into a single cell.

Here is how to get only the headers for example:

```
//*[@id="js-category-content"]/header/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]
```

I'm selecting the 2 element since in the HTML structure the headers are displayed below the values. I will use number 1 in order to get the values.

Once you got the information you need is time to build the table accordingly to your needs:

Since the output of the `IMPORTXML` is in a column I would use `TRANSPOSE` function to display it as a row:

```
    A 
1  https://www.tradingview.com/markets/stocks-australia/sectorandindustry-sector/communications/
2  //*[@id="js-category-content"]/header/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]
3  //*[@id="js-category-content"]/header/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]
.
.
.
10 =TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(A1,A3)) //Stocks    Mkt Cap Volume  Change  Perf Month  Perf Year   Perf YTD
11 =TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(A1,A2)) //23    67.368B 19.335M -1.26%  -2.54%  -3.98%  -4.61%
```

### Reference

[IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en)

[TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en)

Comment: Hi Alessandro, That worked thank you. But what about the second issue, how do I extract "Auto Manufacturers" text, from between the two pipes ?

Comment: As suggested by @marikamitsos please split your question in two different posts. This improves readability and search capabilities.

Consider accepting the answer if it solves your problem, this will help other users to find this solution more easily.